Review Needed: Data Cleaning Methodology for CGM Time Series Data - First Real-World Dataset
I'm working on processing Continuous Glucose Monitor (CGM) data from XDrip+ and would appreciate feedback on my data cleaning methodology. This is my first time working with real-world, "dirty" medical data after learning data science basics.
Here's my current approach:
Glucose Data Processing:

Round timestamps to 5-minute intervals
Create complete timeline with missing value flags
Interpolate gaps up to 20 minutes (4 readings) using linear interpolation
Constrain values to physiological range (39.64-360.36 mg/dL)
Convert to both mg/dL and mmol/L units

Insulin Data Processing:

Parse JSON metadata to identify insulin types (Novorapid/Levemir)
Classify unlabeled insulin based on dosage (≤8 units = bolus, >8 units = basal)
Flag and exclude suspicious entries (unlabeled doses >15 units)
Track confidence with labeled/unlabeled flags

Carbohydrate Data:

Filter out entries <1g (likely errors)
Remove duplicate timestamps

Data Alignment:

Use glucose timeline as master index
Sum multiple insulin/carb entries within same 5-minute window
Fill missing treatments with 0
Preserve glucose NaN values and gap flags

Questions:

Are my validation rules and thresholds reasonable for medical data?
Is linear interpolation appropriate for glucose gaps?
How should I validate the quality of my cleaned dataset?
What critical cleaning steps might I be missing?
Are there established best practices for CGM data that I should follow?

Code provided below. Thanks for your help!
https://github.com/Warren8824/cgm-data-processor
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from typing import Dict


def clean_classify_insulin(df, bolus_limit=8, max_limit=15):
    """
    Clean and classify insulin data into basal and bolus categories.
    Parameters:
        df: DataFrame with insulin and insulinJSON columns
        bolus_limit: Units threshold for classifying unlabeled insulin as bolus
        max_limit: Maximum units allowed for unlabeled insulin


    Returns:
        df_clean: DataFrame with basal, bolus, and labeled_insulin columns with
        datetime index.
    """
    df_clean = df[df['insulin'] > 0.0].copy()
    df_clean = df_clean[~df_clean.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

    # Initialize columns
    df_clean['bolus'] = 0.0
    df_clean['basal'] = 0.0
    # Initialize with explicit bool dtype and set to False
    df_clean['labeled_insulin'] = pd.Series(False, index=df_clean.index, dtype=bool)

    # Process labeled insulin from JSON
    for idx, row in df_clean.iterrows():
        try:
            insulin_data = json.loads(row['insulinJSON'])
            if insulin_data and isinstance(insulin_data, list):
                insulin_type = insulin_data[0].get('insulin', '').lower()
                if 'novorapid' in insulin_type:
                    df_clean.at[idx, 'bolus'] = row['insulin']
                    df_clean.at[idx, 'labeled_insulin'] = True  # Only mark as labeled if explicitly tagged
                elif 'levemir' in insulin_type:
                    df_clean.at[idx, 'basal'] = row['insulin']
                    df_clean.at[idx, 'labeled_insulin'] = True  # Only mark as labeled if explicitly tagged
        except (json.JSONDecodeError, IndexError, KeyError, AttributeError):
            continue

    # Create a mask for unlabeled insulin doses and for doses above 15 units
    unlabeled = (df_clean['bolus'] == 0) & (df_clean['basal'] == 0)
    valid_insulin = df_clean['insulin'] <= max_limit

    # Drop insulin doses which remain unlabeled and fall outside our defined range - > 15 units
    df_clean = df_clean[~(unlabeled & ~valid_insulin)]

    # Classify remaining valid unlabeled insulin based on units - 1-8 = Bolus, >8 = Basal
    # Note: These remain flagged as unlabeled even after classification
    df_clean.loc[unlabeled & valid_insulin & (df_clean['insulin'] <= bolus_limit), 'bolus'] = df_clean['insulin']
    df_clean.loc[unlabeled & valid_insulin & (df_clean['insulin'] > bolus_limit), 'basal'] = df_clean['insulin']

    # Return dataframe containing only insulin related data
    df_clean = df_clean[['basal', 'bolus', 'labeled_insulin']]

    return df_clean



def clean_classify_carbs(df):
    # Create a copy to avoid altering the original dataframe
    df_clean = df.copy()

    # Keep only rows where carbs is >= 1.0 grams
    df_clean = df_clean[df_clean['carbs'] >= 1.0]

    # Drop rows where the index (timestamp) is duplicated
    df_clean = df_clean[~df_clean.index.duplicated(keep='first')]

    # Return DataFrame containing only meal related data
    df_clean = df_clean[['carbs']]

    return df_clean


def clean_glucose(df, interpolation_limit=4):
    # Create a copy to avoid altering original dataframe
    clean_df = df.copy()

    # Round all timestamps to nearest 5 minute interval
    clean_df.index = clean_df.index.round('5min')

    # Keep only the numeric 'calculated_value' column before grouping
    clean_df = clean_df[['calculated_value']]

    # Create complete 5-minute interval index
    full_index = pd.date_range(
        start=clean_df.index.min(),
        end=clean_df.index.max(),
        freq='5min'
    )

    # Reindex to include all intervals and handle duplicate times
    clean_df = clean_df.groupby(level=0).mean().reindex(full_index)

    # Create a flag for all rows with missing data
    clean_df['missing'] = clean_df['calculated_value'].isna()

    # Create groups of consecutive missing values
    # When missing values change (True to False or vice versa), the cumsum increases
    clean_df['gap_group'] = (~clean_df['missing']).cumsum()

    # Within each False group (where missing=True), count the group size
    gap_sizes = clean_df[clean_df['missing']].groupby('gap_group').size()

    # Identify gap groups that are larger than interpolation_limit
    large_gaps = gap_sizes[gap_sizes > interpolation_limit].index

    # Interpolate all gaps initially
    clean_df['calculated_value'] = clean_df['calculated_value'].interpolate(
        method='linear',
        limit=interpolation_limit,
        limit_direction='forward'
    )

    # Reset the interpolated values back to NaN for large gaps
    for gap_group in large_gaps:
        mask = (clean_df['gap_group'] == gap_group) & clean_df['missing']
        clean_df.loc[mask, 'calculated_value'] = np.nan

    # Rename the 'calculated_value' column to 'mg_dl'
    clean_df.rename(columns={'calculated_value': 'mg_dl'}, inplace=True)

    # Limit the 'mg_dl' column values to the range 39.64 to 360.36 (2.2 - 20.0 mmol/L)
    clean_df['mg_dl'] = clean_df['mg_dl'].clip(lower=39.64, upper=360.36)

    # Create a new column 'mmol_l' by converting 'calculated_value' from mg/dL to mmol/L
    clean_df['mmol_l'] = clean_df['mg_dl'] * 0.0555

    # Drop all columns except mg_dl and mmol_l
    clean_df = clean_df[['mg_dl', 'mmol_l', 'missing']]

    return clean_df


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from typing import Dict
from datetime import datetime


def align_diabetes_data(
        bg_df: pd.DataFrame,
        carb_df: pd.DataFrame,
        insulin_df: pd.DataFrame
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Aligns diabetes data (blood glucose, carbohydrates, insulin) to regular 5-minute intervals
    already established in the bg_df dataframe.

    This function takes three dataframes with timestamped diabetes data and produces a single
    dataframe with regular 5-minute intervals. Carbohydrates and insulin entries are summed. This
    dataset is suitable for ML, and other applications where a unified timestamp is required.

    Args:
        bg_df: DataFrame with timestamp index and columns ['mg_dl', 'mmol_l', 'missing']
              Blood glucose readings at irregular intervals
        carb_df: DataFrame with timestamp index and column ['carbs']
                Sporadic carbohydrate entries
        insulin_df: DataFrame with timestamp index and columns ['bolus', 'basal', 'labeled_insulin']
                   Sporadic insulin entries

    Processing steps:
    1. Create copies of dataframes to avoid warnings
    3. Round carbs_df and insulin_df timestamps to nearest 5 minutes
    3a. Resample insulin treatment data - sum any entries within each 5-min window
    3b. Reindex this dataframe to bg_df.index to align timestamps
    4a. Resample carb treatment data - sum any entries within each 5-min window
    4b. Reindex this dataframe to bg_df.index to align timestamps
    5. Combine all data and ensure all intervals exist
    6. Fill missing treatment values with 0 (keep BG as NaN)
    7. Fill missing insulin_labeled rows(where bg_df has index and insulin_resampled does not)
    with False

    Returns:
        DataFrame with:
        - Regular 5-minute interval index
        - Columns: ['mg_dl', 'mmol_l', 'missing', 'carbs', 'bolus', 'basal', 'labeled_insulin']
        - BG values averaged within intervals, NaN where missing
        - Treatment values summed within intervals, 0 where missing
    """
    # First round timestamps in all dataframes to 5-min intervals
    bg_df = bg_df.copy()
    carb_df = carb_df.copy()
    insulin_df = insulin_df.copy()

    # Round index timestamps to nearest 5 minute intervals
    carb_df.index = carb_df.index.round('5min')
    insulin_df.index = insulin_df.index.round('5min')

    # Resample and reindex insulin - sum within windows
    insulin_resampled = insulin_df.resample('5min').agg({
        'bolus': 'sum',
        'basal': 'sum',
        # Use a lambda to ensure empty groups are explicitly False - Empty groups equal True by
        # default
        'labeled_insulin': lambda x: x.all() if len(x) > 0 else False
    }).reindex(bg_df.index)

    # Fill missing labeled_insulin values with False, explicitly astype boolean to avoid warnings
    insulin_resampled['labeled_insulin'] = insulin_resampled['labeled_insulin'].astype('boolean').fillna(False)

    # Resample and reindex carbs - sum within windows
    carb_resampled = carb_df.resample('5min').agg({
        'carbs': 'sum'
    }).reindex(bg_df.index)

    # Combine all data
    aligned_df = pd.concat([bg_df, carb_resampled, insulin_resampled], axis=1)

    # Fill missing treatment values with 0
    aligned_df['carbs'] = aligned_df['carbs'].fillna(0)
    aligned_df[['basal', 'bolus']] = aligned_df[['basal', 'bolus']].fillna(0)


    return aligned_df



This looks well-structured and reasonable for CGM data as far as I can see.. Linear interpolation for glucose gaps up to 20 minutes works, but flag longer gaps and check for anomalies like spikes or flatlines. Insulin thresholds (≤8 units bolus, >8 basal) are a good starting point, but consult clinical guidance for refinement. Ensure duplicates in carb data are summed, not dropped. Validate with pre/post cleaning statistics, visualisations, and domain expert review. Add missing flags for traceability and maintain logs for dropped or altered records. Your modular code is clean and efficient.
